# There are 'n' different things in box 1, same 'n' different things in box 2. I choose 'k' things without replacement from box 1

Tags: probability, combinations

and box 2. What is probability that there is no overlap in 'k' items from box 1 with 'k' items in box 2? You can assume that 'k' is much smaller than n. Each item is equally likely to get selected.

I think the answer is `C(n-k,k)/C(n,k)` because once you select k items you want to pick k items from box 2 that haven't been picked in box 1. Is this right?

I simulated picking 2 things out of 5, i.e. n=5, and k=2 and seeing if the formula worked. I got 3/10 in the formula and running simulations I get 0.55 as the probability.

Answer (score 0):

If $k > \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor +1$ then the probability is zero since you choose more than $n$ items.

Otherwise, you first choose any $k$ items from box $1$. Then you select $k$ things from the $n-k$ things left in the second box.

Comment: I get that part - I am just not sure how that translates mathematically - Is that C(n-k,k)/C(n,k) ?